# Is there a way to blend Android views?

Tags: android, android-view, layer, blending

Image you have a ImageView that takes up the entire screen on a layer that doesn't move, a layer that is constant why the upper layer move when transitioning to new fragment, and then you have another ImageView on a movable layer on top of that. My question is if there is a way to blend the two layers?

Is there a better way to do what I described above?

Comment: So what is the requirement?

Answer (score 5):

Photoshop like blending in Android...

You can use `View.setLayerPaint(paint)` and specify the blendmode inside the `paint.Xfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.<your_mode>))`. Keep in mind that using a hardware layer is much more efficient than a software layer...

This can also be done using `View.setLayerType(layerType,paint)` where you specify the layer type as well.

Android has 3 layer types appearantly,

`LAYER_TYPE_NONE`
`LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`
`LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`

Use the appropriate one correctly... Min. API level required is 17.